# OpenVPN daemon fails to start -- starting server manually returns no output

Tags: security, vpn, configuration, openvpn

I am setting up an openvpn server on my network for the purposes of accessing devices remotely. I have generated crts and keys with the easy-rsa scripts and have configured server.conf correctly AFAIK.

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

returns

```
[FAIL] Starting virtual private network daemon: server failed!
```

I have tried starting the server manually to get more detailed output, but

```
openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

returns no output at all and the process dies before doing anything. Any idea on how to troubleshoot this further?

server.conf:

```
cd /etc/openvpn
remote local
proto udp
port 1194
verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
daemon
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
server 10.1.7.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ips.txt
client-to-client
cipher BF-CBC
secret keys/shared.key
ca certs/ca.crt
dh dh1024.pem
cert certs/server.crt
key keys/server.key
```

Comment: Usually OpenVPN outputs its complaints to syslog. Check your log files.

Comment: You have OpenVPN configured to log explicitly to `/var/log/openvpn.log` (that's what the `log-append` line is for).  Maybe you should look there.